# Excel: screen zooming in/blowing up (sheet zoom % staying the same) when pressing buttons

Tags: excel, vba

Some macro buttons that export data from the sheet when pressed have started causing the display to zoom in. When scrolling or changing tabs, the screen zooms back out. This doesn't happen every time but has started to happen more often.

Note that the macros do not affect the sheets zoom, and the sheet's zoom % stays at 60% the entire time. This also happens on all PCs and all monitors for everyone using the sheet.

I can't work out what is causing it, but assume it is an Excel issue that likely has no fix.

I have looked at the VBA code and nothing is included in it to do with screen displays.

Comment: Try turning off screen updating while doing the export

Comment: I encountered a similar situation, and I discovered that the issue arose when using ActiveX control buttons. Consequently, I switched to using buttons from Form controls, and the problem ceased.